# CSS: Adding Item to list extends <div> up the page, rather than extending the page down

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a list which I can add items to. However, after the list gets to a certain size (5 in my case), the items in the list creep UP the page, rather than the desired (and normal) behaviour of extending down the page and allowing scrolling. I have a feeling this is to do with using CSS grid-templates as I'm a complete newbie to it... I've searched high and low and yet to find any hints!

My code is as follows:

Why are the items in this list creeping up my page once a certain number of items is hit?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #2e112d;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 60px repeat(10, 10%);
  height: 100vh;
}

.nav-bar {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background: #ffdbc5;
  text-align: center;
}

.brand {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1.5%;
}

.background-image {
  grid-row: 2 / 9;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}

.workouts {
  grid-column: 2 / 5;
  grid-row: 2 / -1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.new-workout {
  font-size: 200%;
  color: white;
  background: none;
  border: white 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30%;
  width: 30%;
  grid-row: 1;
  margin: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.workout-list {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  align-self: start;
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 3;
  z-index:1;
}


button.btn {
  color: #5a5a5a;
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  width: 100%
}

span.delete {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div data-reactroot="" class="container">
    <div class="nav-bar"></div>
    <div class="brand">Fiery Leaf</div>
    <div class="background-image">
      <img src="/static/media/landscape-banner.67e9e794.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="workouts">
      <button class="new-workout">New Workout</button>
      <div class="workout-list">
        <div class="workout">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
        <div class="workout">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LroW6.jpg)

[original + 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VFFE.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It looks that your HTML code is broken:

one `button` (the second one) not closed, and an extra `div` ending, messing up the layout of page flow.

Here is the  [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gosicufilu/edit?html,css,js,output) with correct code.

My suggestion: always [validate](https://validator.w3.org) your code.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my code. I've fixed the html code but I'm still having the same problem. The <div class='workouts'>...</div> extends vertically upwards. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure where is the problem... Could you make a screenshot highlighting the issue, and in what point of the page the layout got broken vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding vertical-align: top; to the div that you're extending.

Here's a little example - if you change vertical-align to bottom it will work like you described in your case, I hope that helps:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

p {
  width: 90px;
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.other {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 40px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
</div><div class="other"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for looking but no luck I'm afraid!